# How to do K-means clustering for multiple images in certain directory and save it to another directory? (on local)

Tags: python, image, k-means

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('home.jpg')
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 8
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Above code is simple,basic K-Means clustering code which works well for "single" image. However, I need a code for multiple images in directory.

So, I created code, but its not working with an error: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'reshape' (solved problem)

But after that I have problem with error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'. I think this is because I changed code from

```
img = Image.open(fullpath)
#to
img = np.array(Image.open(fullpath))
```

Below is the code I am working on.

```
path = "Desktop/Gray/fmtial_gb/good_crop/"
sub_path = "Desktop/Gray/fmtial_gb/good_crop_result/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
def kmean():
    from os import listdir,makedirs
    from os.path import isfile,join
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    import os.path, sys
    for item in dirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)
        pathos = os.path.join(sub_path,item)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            #img = Image.open(fullpath)
            img = np.array(Image.open(fullpath))
            f, e = os.path.splitext(pathos)
            #img = cv2.imread('Desktop/Gray/fmtial_gb/good_crop/RD091090(80)Cropped.bmp')
            Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

            # convert to np.float32
            Z = np.float32(Z)

            # define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
            criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
            K = 2
            ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

            # Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
            center = np.uint8(center)
            res = center[label.flatten()]
            res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

            #cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
            #cv2.waitKey(0)
            #cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            Image.fromarray(res2).save(f + 'kmeans.png', "png", quality=100)     
kmean()
```

Comment: Hey guys, anyone can use this code. I edited code and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you are trying to reshape a `PIL` image object instead of a `numpy` array.

Try changing `img = Image.open(fullpath)` to `img = np.array(Image.open(fullpath))` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you Sam, it solved the error. However, I an error message:  'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'. Do you know a way to solve issue about numpy.ndarray?

Comment: Yes, try `Image.from_array(res2).save(f + 'Cropped_Result.png', "png", quality=100`).

Comment: thank you for the reply, it was 99% close. Image.fromarray(res2).save(f + 'kmeans.png', "png", quality=100)